# How can i solve this error in IE ? SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

```
var dataOpt = {
          @foreach($options as $option)
                    @if($option->option_type == 0)
                         Select_{{ $option->id}},
                    @endif
                    @if($option->option_type == 1)
                                    ImageRadio,
                    @endif
          @endforeach
          product_id : {{$product->id}
   };
```

**Note** : This code works in Chrome but in IE 11 returns the error:

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' on line 5.
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Show the rendered javascript shown in your browser. You'd be better off building an array in php, then echoing `json_encode($array)`, so that you have a properly formatted json.

Comment: So what does it actually output?

Comment: Output it's here ; https://imgyukle.com/i/k1TZAA

Comment: output in chore and ie it's here https://imgyukle.com/i/ex.k1T6vI

Comment: You definitely need to create an array first and then echo the encoded json, and figure out what the correct structure needs to be. Right now, you have a bunch of properties without values, and one property with a value. Should the `Select_` and `ImageRadio` be part of an array inside of the object?

Comment: Please add the generated data (the one that leads to that error message) to the question itself

Comment: yes, the two is part of an array of the object .

Comment: I don't understand , why it doesn't work in IE , in chrome and in another browser work it , but  I meet this error only in EI .

Comment: You must try to set a value for every attribute that is inside your object and make sure the value you want to affect to the key is not empty, if its, then in this case you must set the key with an empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is not valid json. Your properties do not have values and their names should be enclosed in double quotes. You could try something like the following:

```
{
  "options": ["Select_3", "Select_4", "Select_13"],
  "product_id": 10
}
```